# "One of X and Y" or "One of X or Y"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

The following sentences are error messages a software gives out, when insufficient parameters are provided. ('searchterm' and 'pageindex' are possible parameters.)

- "You need to specify at least one of 'searchterm' and 'pageindex'."
- "You need to specify at least one of 'searchterm' or 'pageindex'."

Which of these sentences is grammatically correct? If they are both correct, is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these are correct and have separate meanings:

"You need to specify at least one of 'searchterm' and 'pageindex': This means you need to have one searchterm and one pageindex. It only works if you have both instances.

"You need to specify at least one of 'searchterm' or 'pageindex': This means you don't need both, only one. One searchterm and zero 'pageindex's would work.

Comment: I think the second part of your answer got cut off, but the first part already answers my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! And you're welcome!